# template_include doesn't work with child theme

Tags: child-theme, template-include

I am using this code and it works perfectly but it does not work if I activate the child theme how can I solve?

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_template_include' );
function wpse_template_include( $template ) {
    // Handle taxonomy templates.
    $taxonomy = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    if ( is_tax() && $taxonomy ) {
        $file = get_theme_file_path() . '/template-parts/taxonomies/taxonomy-' . $taxonomy . '.php';
        if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
            $template = $file;
        }           
}
return $template;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! just need to change

```
get_theme_file_path()
```

to

```
get_template_directory()
```